# Adobe Spark cannot detect WebGL

Tags: windows-7, opera, webgl

I was working with Adobe Spark, and it was doing well. But when I started using it again (after having my PC to sleep), it says this:

> ### WebGL Disabled
>
> Oops! Looks like your browser has WebGL disabled. Please visit our support page or consult your IT organization for more information.

However, when I accessed the [GetWebGL](https://get.webgl.org) website, I could see that spinning cube.

I also checked my browser settings, and saw that ***Use hardware acceleration when available*** was already enabled.

My specifications:

1. Browser - **Opera 49.0.2725.64**
2. Computer Model - **Dell Vostro 1500**
3. Operating System - **Windows 7 x86**

Comment: Do you have the appropriate display drivers installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restart the browser, and it would be detected by Adobe Spark.